# Delete a certain part of a line in a file

Tags: python

So I have a list that looks something like this

```
Cell number:1,R0:0.03337,R1:0.00842,DCR:0.04179
Cell number:2,R0:0.03142,R1:0.00754,DCR:0.03895
Cell number:3,R0:0.03347,R1:0.00871,DCR:0.04218
Cell number:4,R0:0.03377,R1:0.00832,DCR:0.04208
Cell number:5,R0:0.03259,R1:0.00842,DCR:0.04101
Cell number:6,R0:0.03142,R1:0.00812,DCR:0.03954
Cell number:7,R0:0.03181,R1:0.00812,DCR:0.03993
Cell number:8,R0:0.03112,R1:0.00930,DCR:0.04042
Cell number:9,R0:0.03122,R1:0.00773,DCR:0.03895
Cell number:10,R0:0.03582,R1:0.00881,DCR:0.04463
```

This is just a part of it but one thing I can't figure out is how I can make a program that reads just the numbers after the `Cell number` (1,2,3,4...) and the last number just after `DCR`:

I have tried with reading the words but that would be impossible due to the fact that the numbers in the middle are always changing.

Comment: you can approach it with regex. - https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Use a regex; or read line by line, splitting on comma and then on colon; or read as CSV, then split individual cells on a colon.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

s = '''Cell number:1,R0:0.03337,R1:0.00842,DCR:0.04179
Cell number:2,R0:0.03142,R1:0.00754,DCR:0.03895
Cell number:3,R0:0.03347,R1:0.00871,DCR:0.04218
Cell number:4,R0:0.03377,R1:0.00832,DCR:0.04208
Cell number:5,R0:0.03259,R1:0.00842,DCR:0.04101
Cell number:6,R0:0.03142,R1:0.00812,DCR:0.03954
Cell number:7,R0:0.03181,R1:0.00812,DCR:0.03993
Cell number:8,R0:0.03112,R1:0.00930,DCR:0.04042
Cell number:9,R0:0.03122,R1:0.00773,DCR:0.03895
Cell number:10,R0:0.03582,R1:0.00881,DCR:0.04463'''

cell_numbers = re.findall(r'Cell number:([\d.]+)', s)
dcr = re.findall(r'DCR:([\d.]+)', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what you want to achieve

```
import re

lst = '''Cell number:1,R0:0.03337,R1:0.00842,DCR:0.04179
Cell number:2,R0:0.03142,R1:0.00754,DCR:0.03895
Cell number:3,R0:0.03347,R1:0.00871,DCR:0.04218
Cell number:4,R0:0.03377,R1:0.00832,DCR:0.04208
Cell number:5,R0:0.03259,R1:0.00842,DCR:0.04101
Cell number:6,R0:0.03142,R1:0.00812,DCR:0.03954
Cell number:7,R0:0.03181,R1:0.00812,DCR:0.03993
Cell number:8,R0:0.03112,R1:0.00930,DCR:0.04042
Cell number:9,R0:0.03122,R1:0.00773,DCR:0.03895
Cell number:10,R0:0.03582,R1:0.00881,DCR:0.04463'''

pattern = r'^Cell number:(\d+).*DCR:(\d+\.\d+)$'

for s in lst.split('\n'):
    match = re.match(pattern, s)
    if match:
        print(match)
        cell_number = match.group(1)
        dcr = match.group(2)
        print(f"Cell number {cell_number}, DCR: {dcr}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using build-in functions. `str.partition` split the string at the first match of the pattern, hence starting from the left, and returns what is on left, the pattern and what is on the right. `str.rpartition` same but starts from the end of the string.

```
text = """Cell number:1,R0:0.03337,R1:0.00842,DCR:0.04179
Cell number:2,R0:0.03142,R1:0.00754,DCR:0.03895
Cell number:3,R0:0.03347,R1:0.00871,DCR:0.04218
Cell number:4,R0:0.03377,R1:0.00832,DCR:0.04208
Cell number:5,R0:0.03259,R1:0.00842,DCR:0.04101
Cell number:6,R0:0.03142,R1:0.00812,DCR:0.03954
Cell number:7,R0:0.03181,R1:0.00812,DCR:0.03993
Cell number:8,R0:0.03112,R1:0.00930,DCR:0.04042
Cell number:9,R0:0.03122,R1:0.00773,DCR:0.03895
Cell number:10,R0:0.03582,R1:0.00881,DCR:0.04463"""


def cell_number(text) -> str:
    _, _, right = text.partition(':')
    c_num , _, _ = right.partition(',')
    return c_num

def DCR(text) -> str:
    _, _, dcr = text.rpartition(':')
    return dcr


new_text = ""
for line in text.split('\n'):
    cn = cell_number(line)
    dcr = DCR(line)
    new_text += f"{cn},{dcr}\n" # ,-separated values

new_text = new_text.rstrip() # remove last end of line
print(new_text)
```

Output

```
1,0.04179
2,0.03895
3,0.04218
4,0.04208
5,0.04101
6,0.03954
7,0.03993
8,0.04042
9,0.03895
10,0.04463
```

---

A regex approach:

- `\d+(?=,R0)`: is a *lookahead assertion* which matches any digits followed by `,R0`
- `(?<=,DCR:)\S+`: is a *positive lookbehind assertion* which matches anything after `,DCR` which is not a whitespace characters (in this case the line break)
- `|`: or-like operator. It alternates the two above patterns

```
text = # from above

ms = []
row = ""
for i, match in enumerate(re.finditer(r"\d+(?=,R0)|(?<=,DCR:)\S+", text)):
    row += match.group()
    if i % 2:
        ms.append(row)
        row = ""
    else:
        row += "," # separator

new_text = '\n'.join(ms)
```

The above *for*-loop can be avoided using a pairwise approach for example provided by `itertools.pairwise` with Python3.10+:

```
import itertools as it

# ...

row_format = "{},{}"
new_text = '\n'.join(it.starmap(row_format.format, 
    it.pairwise(m.group() for m in re.finditer(r"\d+(?=,R0)|(?<=,DCR:)\S+", text)
    )))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to create a line parser if the data is always in the same format. I'd go with something similar to this:

```
lines = '''Cell number:1,R0:0.03337,R1:0.00842,DCR:0.04179
Cell number:2,R0:0.03142,R1:0.00754,DCR:0.03895
Cell number:3,R0:0.03347,R1:0.00871,DCR:0.04218
Cell number:4,R0:0.03377,R1:0.00832,DCR:0.04208
Cell number:5,R0:0.03259,R1:0.00842,DCR:0.04101
Cell number:6,R0:0.03142,R1:0.00812,DCR:0.03954
Cell number:7,R0:0.03181,R1:0.00812,DCR:0.03993
Cell number:8,R0:0.03112,R1:0.00930,DCR:0.04042
Cell number:9,R0:0.03122,R1:0.00773,DCR:0.03895
Cell number:10,R0:0.03582,R1:0.00881,DCR:0.04463'''

result = []
for line in lines.split('\n'):
    line_dict = dict([part.split(':') for part in line.split(',')])
    result.append([line_dict['Cell number'], line_dict['DCR']])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_text = '''Cell number:1,R0:0.03337,R1:0.00842,DCR:0.04179
Cell number:2,R0:0.03142,R1:0.00754,DCR:0.03895
Cell number:3,R0:0.03347,R1:0.00871,DCR:0.04218
Cell number:4,R0:0.03377,R1:0.00832,DCR:0.04208
Cell number:5,R0:0.03259,R1:0.00842,DCR:0.04101
Cell number:6,R0:0.03142,R1:0.00812,DCR:0.03954
Cell number:7,R0:0.03181,R1:0.00812,DCR:0.03993
Cell number:8,R0:0.03112,R1:0.00930,DCR:0.04042
Cell number:9,R0:0.03122,R1:0.00773,DCR:0.03895
Cell number:10,R0:0.03582,R1:0.00881,DCR:0.04463'''

list_01 = txt.split('\n')

my_data = map(lambda x : x[x.index(':')+1:x.index(',')] + " " + x[x.index('DCR:')+4:], list_01)

for val in my_data :
        print(val)
```